# Post-build event xcopy - how to copy linked files?

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, xcopy, post-build

In project i have as normal files as links (shortcuts) to existing file:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UmXPyNY.jpg]

In post-build event i want to copy all files, including links (but as real file) to other directory, for example:

```
"%RELEASEPATH%\Code\"
```

Using default **xcopy** command it do copy all files + directory, but not links:

```
xcopy /E /Y /R "$(ProjectDir)Code" "%RELEASEPATH%\Code\"
```

If there a way to copy linked files (as real files) with xcopy as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of xcopy, but if all you want is for copying the link file to the folder you put the link file in, then you can try:

(source from [Copying linked content files at each build using MSBuild](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx))

> build by adding the following at the end of the .csproj file, just
>   before the final  tag:

```
 <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
          DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles='true' 
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles='true' 
          Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
 </Target>
```

Comment: i added this, but its didn't take any effect (i didn't found files anywhere). Also i want to copy those files to **specific location**, in my case i specified it within post-build actions as: "%RELEASEPATH%\Code\"